# Detect empty key in pgfkeys without `.get` code

Tags: pgfkeys

I am trying to use `pgfkeys` to define an API for some macros, and I am having trouble detecting when a key is "empty". Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163607/check-the-value-of-a-pgfkey), I have come up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\specialsave}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{
        /specialstore/place/.cd,
        a/.initial,
        c/.initial,#1,  % there cannot be a newline before #1
        c/.get=\cvalA,  % this must come after #1, otherwise it won't get the values that are set
    }

    \edef\cvalB{\pgfkeysvalueof{/specialstore/place/c}}
    \def\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue}
    \ifdefequal{\cvalA}{\compareval}{c is empty by comparison A}{c is non-empty by comparison A}

    \ifdefequal{\cvalB}{\compareval}{c is empty by comparison B}{c is non-empty by comparison B}
}
\begin{document}
    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c=
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c={}
    }
\end{document}
```

which produces:

```
c is empty by comparison A
c is non-empty by comparison B

c is empty by comparison A
c is non-empty by comparison B

c is non-empty by comparison A
c is non-empty by comparison B

c is non-empty by comparison A
c is non-empty by comparison B
```

My question is

1. How can I detect empty values in `\cvalB`, and
2. How can I detect that the values in cases `c=` and `c={}` are "empty"?

Answer (score 1):

I only added `\edef\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue}` and obtained

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\specialsave}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{
        /specialstore/place/.cd,
        a/.initial,
        c/.initial,#1,  % there cannot be a newline before #1
        c/.get=\cvalA,  % this must come after #1, otherwise it won't get the values that are set

    }

    \edef\cvalB{\pgfkeysvalueof{/specialstore/place/c}} 
    \def\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue}
    \ifdefequal{\cvalA}{\compareval}{c is empty by comparison A}{c is non-empty by comparison A}
    \edef\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue} %<-
    \ifdefequal{\cvalB}{\compareval}{c is empty by comparison B}{c is non-empty by comparison B}
}
\begin{document}
    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c=
    }
\\

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c={}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

This means that the second comparison seems to do what you wanted to do.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\specialsave}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{
        /specialstore/place/.cd,
        a/.initial,
        c/.initial,#1,  % there cannot be a newline before #1
    }

    \edef\cvalB{\pgfkeysvalueof{/specialstore/place/c}} 
    \edef\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue} %<-
    \ifdefequal{\cvalB}{\compareval}{c is empty}{c is non-empty}
}
\begin{document}
    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
    }

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c
    }

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c=
    }

    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c={}
    }


    \specialsave{
        a=the values of a,
        c={pft}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! It seems to break the comparison with `\cvalA`, though... Can you explain why it works?

Comment: @JasonSiefken Could you please explain what is meant by "It seems to break the comparison with \cvalA, though."? The reason why this works is that I expand both `\edef\cvalB{\pgfkeysvalueof{/specialstore/place/c}}` and `\edef\compareval{\pgfkeysnovalue}`, and compare the expanded values. In your code, only the first one is expanded, so you compare an expanded value with an unexpanded one.

Comment: Using the `\edef\cmpareval{\pgfkeysnovalue}` version, `\ifdefequal{\cvalA}{\compareval}{c is empty}{c is non-empty}` reports `c is non-empty` in the first two cases.

Comment: @JasonSiefken From the title of your question "Detect empty key in pgfkeys without `.get` code" I was under the impression that you only want the B check to work. (I just realized that the above code really did not work because I again lost again the editor of this site. I fixed this. The lower code does not use `.get` and works.)